# Run two scripts simultaneously on one google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Good morning,

I'm very new to scripting and I have two scripts on my file that work fine independently (either one or the other) but I will need both scripts to run at the same time at all times . Here are my two scripts hoping you can help me get them working simultaneously.

Script 1:

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,4];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Work'


function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//checks that we're on the correct sheet.
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
//checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Script 2

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 4;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,4];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Work'


function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//checks that we're on the correct sheet.
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
//checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

As you can see the two are similar but one is to enter the date of the day when a column is modified and the other is to enter the date of the day when another column is modified. I entrust you my file to be more clear.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n3yOUo86zoArPVeecerl9Pfblq53gxTinfPAe6xIgRk/edit?usp=share_l...

Comment: See [Which function runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906642/13045193).

Answer (score 0):

Since the scripts are the same with the exception of the `var COLUMNTOCHECK` you just need to run one of the scripts but have it check if the column matches one of two values.

##### Change 1

```
Original:     var COLUMNTOCHECK =

Replacement:  var COLUMNTOCHECK01 =
              var COLUMNTOCHECK02 =
```

##### Change 2

```
Original:     if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {

Replacement:  if( ( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK01 ) ||
                  ( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK02 ) ) {
```

##### New Code

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

// CORE VARIABLES
// The columns you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK01 = 2;
var COLUMNTOCHECK02 = 4;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,4];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Work'

function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {

    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
   
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( ( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK01 ) ||
        ( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK02 ) ) {
    
       var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
       dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

  }

}
```